# How to fix a defective JSON string?

Tags: php, json, regex, string, regex-negation

I need to know what data format is this and what process do I use to get the data from "nickname". I got this data from a $_REQUEST:

```
{id:10,Username:gab@gmail.com,nickname:gabe}
```

Here is an example of a JSON format. it has quotation marks:

```
$json = '
{
    "type": "donut",
    "name": "Cake"
}';
```

Then you could just call the type by putting the lines:

```
$yummy = json_decode($json);

echo $yummy->type; //donut
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: it seems like it should be json, but whoever implemented it screwed up. talk to whoever made that request and tell them not to roll their own json, because they are doing it wrong.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann  Thanks for the help!  You are correct in this one.

Answer (score 0):

That is a string, which we can use an expression with `preg_match_all` and json it:

```
$re = '/([^{}]+?):([^{}]+?),|([^{}]+):([^{}]+)/m';
$str = '{id:10,Username:gab@gmail.com,nickname:gabe}';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

$json_str = '{';
foreach ($matches as $value) {
    if (!$value[3] && !$value[4]) {
        $json_str .= '"' . $value[1] . '":"' . $value[2] . '",';
    } else {
        $json_str .= '"' . $value[3] . '":"' . $value[4] . '"';
    }
}

$json_str .= '}';

var_dump(json_decode($json_str, true));
```

#### Outputs

```
{"id":"10","Username":"gab@gmail.com","nickname":"gabe"}
```

---

```
array(3) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(2) "10"
  ["Username"]=>
  string(13) "gab@gmail.com"
  ["nickname"]=>
  string(4) "gabe"
}
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/6BN3Tg/1/)

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]